# Set Band Override in Infragistics 9.2 Winform Grid bound to IBindingList<T>

Tags: .net, infragistics

I am brand-new to Infragistics grids and need to set an overall Band override on my grid to stop the '+' expansion indicator when there are no child rows( Override.ExpansionIndicator = ShowExpansionIndicator.CheckOnDisplay).

My grid is bound to an object that implements IBindingList, so I gather that any performance hit will be minmial.

My question is where/when is best to set the Override? I don't see me having much luck with DisplayLayout.Bands[n] until the bands actually exist...

EDIT: At the moment I am doing it just after the data is bound - will that do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after the data bind seems to work Ok so I'll consider that the answer.